# How to change the difficulty of a field in GemCraft Chasing Shadows?

Tags: gemcraft-chasing-shadows

GemCraft Chasing Shadows is finally out, after months of waiting!

For some reason, I don't manage to change the difficulty of a given field, even when I try redoing them. It seems I need more shadow cores for it, but I can't find how many, and the difficulty stays at "Looming".

Anybody know more about this?

Comment: I unlocked it by beating a Shadow for the first time. I'm not sure if it's any shadow or if it's on a specific field, but you do have to unlock the extra difficulty(ies?).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They need to be unlocked before you can play them. Like other [Battle Traits](http://gemcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_Traits_%28GC2%29), they are unlocked by beating certain fields. For **Glaring** difficulty you need to beat field **K4** and for **Haunting** difficulty you need to beat field **T6** which you can only play if you have the Magician Pouch.

After you unlock it you can play any field on that difficulty even if you didn't beat it yet.

Answer (score 3):

From armor games comments:
 thunderrider Anamatron • 5 hours ago

"Glaring"(next step up) is found in the K sector I believe. Haunting, the highest difficulty, is only for premium, but has to be found in the wilderness after bought. Hope I helped.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is on Field K4. Have fun!